# find links in pdf

Tags: command-line, pdf

I need to find all links in a pdf file, but also their position x,y on those pages. I want to create pictures out of a pdf (that I know hw to do) which I will use on a web site, but I need to know about those links too. What ever you can give, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

1/2 answer !

To find back the links you could start playing with

```
pdftotext -layout yourpdf.pdf
```

and then you will have to script around with the generated text yourpdf.txt file and a grep command.
Knowing the exact xy location of each link is out of my knowledge !